# Gdb weird behaviour wrt printf vs strcpy [shared library load]

Tags: c, gdb

From the book `Hacking the art of exploitation`, the author shows the following results -

```sh
$ cat test1.c

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char str_a[20];

    strcpy(str_a, "Hello, World!\n");
    printf("%s",str_a);
}

$ gcc -g -o test1 test1.c
$ gdb -q ./test1
Reading symbols from ./test1...done.

(gdb) break strcpy
Function "strcpy" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n])
```

But when I do:

```sh
(gdb) break printf
Breakpoint 1 at 0x580
```

There is no warning message from gdb as such, since the compiler placed printf to a specified location (stdio.h but not string.h?). Why is there a difference in behavior of printf and strcpy?

Further to elaborate my understanding.

```sh
$ objdump -D test1 | grep printf
0000000000000580 <printf@plt>:
 580:   ff 25 4a 0a 20 00       jmpq   *0x200a4a(%rip)        # 200fd0 <printf@GLIBC_2.2.5>
 6f6:   e8 85 fe ff ff          callq  580 <printf@plt>
$ objdump -D test1 | grep strcpy
$
```

Am I missing something, why isn't strcpy from string.h loaded during compile time?